# Injecting & using Firebug-Lite with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, firebug-lite

I'm trying to inject Firebug & jQuery into a webpage using PhantomJS, but I'm unable to access them.

I've tried both PhantomJS methods for adding other JS to a page: page.injectJs() and page.includeJs.

I'm not able to get anything returned from includeJs (which I wasn't expecting to get, from reading the documentation).

After I injectJs() and try to use firebug-lite and jQuery functions or objects (like $ and inspect() ) I get errors saying they are undefined or the variable can't be found.

This is my complete script. You can also see it here: http://piratepad.net/XTPefXOB4o

```
"use strict";
"use warnings";

var page = new WebPage(), address;
var useragent = "PhantomJS Firebug integration tool (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11";

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log("+eval:" + msg);
};

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        console.log("got into page.open()");

        var testInclude = page.includeJs("http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.4/firebug-lite.js", function () {
            var result = true;
            try {
                inspect($("*")[5]);
            }
            catch(err) {
                result = false;
            }
            console.log("from includeJS: " + result);
            return result;
            // is there any way to return a value from this?
        });

        var results = page.evaluate( function () {      
            var debug = [];

            try {
                page.injectJs("http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.4/firebug-lite.js");
                page.injectJs("http://pconerly.webfactional.com/site_media/js/jquery-1.7.min.js");
            } catch(err) {
                debug[0] = false;
            }
            debug[0] = true;

            debug[1] = true;
            try {
                // all 3 of these commands fail.
                //$(document);
                inspect(document.querySelectorAll("*")[i]);
                //firebug;
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message)
                debug[1] = false;
            }

            //debug[1] = inspectAEl(5);

            return debug; 
        });

        var stuff = results;
        console.log("did not error on injecting JS: " + stuff[0]);
        console.log("used inspect within page.evaluate: " + stuff[1]);

        console.log("return value from includeJs: " + testInclude);

        console.log("processing finished");            
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This is my output:

```
$ phantomjs firebug-integration.js 
got into page.open()
+eval:Can't find variable: inspect
did not error on injecting JS: true
used inspect within page.evaluate: false
return value from includeJs: undefined
processing finished
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got some confusion here around the context of each function:

- When you run `includeJs(url, callback)`, the `callback` function runs in the PhantomJS context. So it has access to `page`, but does *not* have access to variables and namespaces created by the included script - these were included in the *client* context, and will be available to functions you run through `page.evaluate()`.
- You're trying to run `page.injectJs()` within `page.evaluate()`. This won't work - the function you run in `page.evaluate()` is sandboxed in the client execution context, and does not have access to the `page` object.

So you should try one of these approaches - either run `page.evaluate()` in the `page.includeJs()` callback:

```
    page.includeJs("http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.4/firebug-lite.js", 
        function () {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                // do stuff with firebug lite here
                console.log(inspect($("*")[5]));
            });
        });
```

or run `page.injectJs()` and *then* run `page.evaluate()`:

```
// note - this is a reference to a local file
page.injectJs("firebug-lite.js");
page.evaluate(function() {
    // do stuff with firebug lite here
    console.log(inspect($("*")[5]));
});
```