# Capybara/Poltergeist/PhantomJS use page.evaluate_script to return elements

Tags: angularjs, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

In Selenium/Chromedriver it is possible to execute arbitrary jQuery selectors and receive a list of native Selenium::WebDriver::Elements:

```
page.evaluate_script("$('.some_class')")

=> [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x1 id="...">, ...]
```

When I execute the same selector in in Poltergeist/PhantomJS I get the following:

```
page.evaluate_script("$('.some_class')")

=> "(cyclic structure)"
```

Is there any way to get Poltegeist/PhantomJS to return the Poltergeist-equivalent list of elements?

I know about find(:css, ".some_class"), but I'm trying to expose Angular's getTestability interface to access models, bindings, etc from within Capybara...see [capybara-ng](https://github.com/kikonen/capybara-ng), which only works in Selenium.

Comment: This is probably not easily doable, because GhostDriver (the WebDriver implementation of PhantomJS) is running in the page context and it is not possible to pass DOM elements from the page context to the outside. So they have to be mapped somehow.

Comment: You will have to write your test script completely in the page context (in `page.evaluate_script()`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting & using Firebug-Lite with PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728673/injecting-using-firebug-lite-with-phantomjs)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? Because I am having the exact same issue as you!